# syntax error foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to php/sql and i'm getting a syntax error on the line with the foreign key.

Syntax error or access violation: 1064

```
    $createQuery ="CREATE TABLE AthleteTable
    (
        athleteID   INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        lastName    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        firstName   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        gender      CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
        image       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        eventID     INT(6) NOT NULL, 
        medal       VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,

        CONSTRAINT foreign FOREIGN KEY (eventID) REFERENCES eventsTable(eventID),
        PRIMARY KEY(athleteID)

    )";
```

If any one knows what is wrong would appreciate some help.

------------>

new error:

> inserting data AthleteTable failed SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`powlz1_in612`.`AthleteTable`, CONSTRAINT
>   `AthleteTable_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`eventID`) REFERENCES `eventsTable`
>   (`eventID`))

here is where I make the tables:

```
$createQuery ="CREATE TABLE eventsTable
    (
        eventID     INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        sport       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        event       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,

        PRIMARY KEY (eventID)

    )";
    $pdo->exec($createQuery);

    $createQuery ="CREATE TABLE AthleteTable
    (
        athleteID       INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        firstName       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        lastName        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        gender          VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        image           VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        eventID         INT(20) NOT NULL,
        medal           VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,

        CONSTRAINT SportEvents FOREIGN KEY (`eventID`) REFERENCES      eventsTable(`eventID`),
        PRIMARY KEY(`athleteID`)

    )";
    $pdo->exec($createQuery);
```

after looking at others questions it all seems to be a missing field, but both tables include an eventID so I don't get why it is failing?

Answer (score 3):

```
$createQuery ="CREATE TABLE AthleteTable
(
    athleteID   INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    lastName    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    firstName   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    gender      CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    image       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    eventID     INT(6) NOT NULL, 
    medal       VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT  FOREIGN KEY (eventID) REFERENCES eventsTable(eventID),
    PRIMARY KEY(athleteID)

)";
```

You had the word `FOREIGN` twice. That solved your 1064.

Read comments below about your 1452 error that would follow due to setup issues on your referenced table.

Comment: I changed that and still got the error, there was an error in another file which when fixed resolved this one somehow, thanks tho.

Comment: It banks on the other index and columns ready to accept the FK. But that at least removed your 1064

Comment: Got a new error, 1452. Any ideas what's causing that? I've edited the original post with it :)

Comment: Right, this original question and this answer solved your 1064. The 1452 would be the next error (a different question) because the referenced table is not ready to accept the FK

Comment: `eventsTable(eventID)` need to be ready. Same datatype, and an index. That has to occur FIRST

Comment: Here is the manual page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html